# Holding pointers to structs inside of the same struct (C)

Tags: c

I'm currently writing a small compiler in C and am running into a weird issue that seems to be something to do with how I'm storing pointers to structs in an array, inside of the same struct. I have a struct SymbolTable that looks like this:

```
typedef struct SymbolTable_t
{
    // testing
    int id;

    Symbol symbols[40];
    int count;
    struct SymbolTable_t * parent;

    int scopeCount;
    struct SymbolTable_t * childScopes[40];
} SymbolTable;
```

And when I want to create a new SymbolTable, I pass a pointer to its parent as an argument, and the parent also gets a pointer to this new child added to its childScopes array, like so:

```
SymbolTable createSymbolTable(SymbolTable* parent)
{
    //if(parent->scopeCount == 1) printf("%d\n", parent->childScopes[0]->id);

    SymbolTable t;
    t.count = 0;
    t.scopeCount = 0;
    t.parent = parent;

    memset(t.symbols, 0, 40*sizeof(Symbol));
    for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        t.childScopes[i] = (SymbolTable *)malloc(sizeof(SymbolTable));
    }

    if(parent != NULL)
    { 
        addChildScope(parent, &t);
    }

    return t;
}

void addChildScope(SymbolTable* parent, SymbolTable* child)
{
    parent->childScopes[parent->scopeCount] = child;
    parent->scopeCount++;
}
```

This seems like a simple system that should work to me, however sometimes when I  create a new SymbolTable that shares a parent with another, the data in this older SymbolTable gets overwritten, as if the childScopes array isn't getting properly updated? I think I've narrowed the problem down to these small functions so I assumed I was getting some kind of stack overflow or something but I haven't been able to find a problem with the code.

NB: If I uncomment the first line of createSymbolTable, I get a segfault even though I obviously  shouldn't, since if scopeCount is 1, then the first element of childScopes should contain a SymbolTable. (I'm aware ID will be garbage, I'm just trying to check childScopes with this test)

I'm really unsure of what's causing this, any help would be very much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: If you get a segfault, then one of your pointers is wrong. The segfault should already have given you that hint.

Comment: _[...] a new SymbolTable that shares a parent with another [...]_ I think the code which causes the issue is not shown. Probably you free a parent before all childs are freed.

Comment: I removed all my free calls elsewhere in the program for testing, as that's what I thought it might be aswell but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the call

```
addChildScope(parent, &t);
```

Here you pass a pointer to the ***local*** variable `t`. And as all local variables its life-time ends with the end of the function it's defined in (i.e. it ceases to exist once `createSymbolTable` returns) leaving you with an invalid pointer.

To create a new structure you need to dynamically allocate it using `malloc`.

Comment: Ok this makes alot of sense, and did indeed fix my problem. Thanks alot.

Comment: @JamesMclaughlin Remember to return the pointer, not the structure object.

Comment: Yea I changed the function to do that instead. Would this be more of the standard practice in C, returning a pointer to a structure rather than the struct itself?

Comment: @JamesMclaughlin It's definitely more used. Especially since it solves the whole possible "pointer to local variable" issue on many levels.